# Bootloop with additional drive attached

Tags: linux, usb, debian

i'm working on a raspberry pi4b with debian 12 lite on, I'm booting from an usb ssd (sda) with no issue. As soon as I connect and mount another external usb drive (sdb) I'm getting into this boot loop that stops only if I disconnect sdb, I tried both with an usb  hub that without but with no luck. Sdb contains only media files.

I tried to recreate the issue and check what's happening on a monitor. As soon I as connect a drive during normal OS operation (tried also with another one), I get this message "EXT4-fs errore (device sda2) in ext4_reverse_inode_write:5086: Journal as aborted. EXT4-fs error (device sda2) in ext4_convert_unwritten_extents:4020: inode 126501: comm kworker/u8:2: mark_inode_dirty error EXT4-fs error (device sda2) failed to convert unwritten extents to written extents -- potential data loss! (inode 126501, errir -30) EXT4-fs error (device sda2), remount filesystem read-only

sda2 belongs to the OS filesystem

Tried with a different USB Port, same issue both with or without the hub.

This Is the external drive I'm using, no external Power supply. https://www.westerndigital.com/it-it/products/portable-drives/wd-elements-portable-usb-3-0-hdd?sku=WDBU6Y0040BBK-WESN

I'm using the official Power supply for Raspberry.

Tried to have a powered USB hub and change the external storage drive, same issue.

@hannu "I'd wager that the new device changes the device names such that the root partition cannot be identified by the method that is in use" Any suggestion for checking if your wager is a winner?

Comment: What is your boot configuration on this device? Does using a different 2nd USB cause the same issue?

Comment: @music2myear After running sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit, that's my result 
[all]
BOOT_UART=0
WAKE_ON_GPIO=1
POWER_OFF_ON_HALT=0

[all]
BOOT_ORDER=0xf14

Comment: "As soon as I connect and mount […] I'm getting into this boot loop" – Do you mean the actual `mount` command? To cast it, you need to boot successfully. So you boot successfully, cast `mount /dev/sdb …` (what is the actual command?) and then what? Does the boot loop happens immediately? Or only after reboot? What happens when you connect the troublesome drive, do not mount it, reboot?

Comment: I'd wager that the new device changes the device names such that the root partition cannot be identified by the method that is in use.

Comment: Ok, i tried to recreate the issue and check whats happening on a monitor. As soon I as connect a drive (tried also with another one), I get this message "EXT4-fs errore (device sda2) in ext4_reverse_inode_write:5086: Journal as aborted.
EXT4-fs error (device sda2) in ext4_convert_unwritten_extents:4020: inode 126501: comm kworker/u8:2: mark_inode_dirty error
EXT4-fs error (device sda2) failed to convert unwritte extents to written extents -- potential data loss! (inode 126501, errir -30)
EXT4-fs error (device sda2), remount filesysteam read-only

Comment: (1) Additional information should be added to the question body, comments are not for this. Please take our short [tour] to see how the site is designed to work, then [edit] the question and add information there. (2) "As soon I as connect a drive" – Is this during normal operation of the OS? i.e. when the OS has already finished booting up? (3) In your last comment, does `sda2` belong to the newly connected device? or to the one the OS itself uses?

Comment: Do the drives use external power supplies? If not then maybe the additional drive draws so much power from the Pi that the main drive gets under-powered and bad things happen. I read that [maximum total current for all 4 USB ports is 1.2 A](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#typical-power-requirements). For USB the voltage is 5 V, so the maximum power is 6 W. Depending on the SSDs and additional USB hardware (if any), maybe the act of connecting the additional drive exceeds the limit. Tell us more about the USB devices connected and their power supplies.

Comment: "same issue both with or without hub" – Does the hub provide additional power? Or is the Pi the only source of electrical power for the USB devices in question? Can you try with a USB hub that provides power? Or can you get the HDD out of the enclosure and connect it via a SATA-USB bridge that uses its own power supply? (Note not all enclosures can be easily opened; and not all of them are SATA-USB bridges with a generic SATA disk you can use as any SATA disk. I don't really know what your enclosure and HDD are. So even if you have a separate SATA-USB bridge, maybe you can use it, maybe not.)